# Reading chat messages using FQL

Tags: facebook, chat, facebook-fql

Do anyone know when the following FQL tables will be opened for all users and not only for developers?

- unified_thread
- unified_message

According to the documentation below, Facebook do plan to open these FQL tables:

> Please note: We are in the process of making the new messages system available to all users, at which point this table will replace the existing thread table. We are providing early access to this API for registered developer accounts only until the new messaging system is broadly available.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/unified_thread/

Answer (score 0):

This message no longer appears above so you can assume that it is open for all.

Also the new messaging system has been rolled out for a while now.